Error Starting op-geth Node with Archive Mode: "incompatible state scheme
I am following the Optimism documentation to set up a Layer 2 Rollup testnet and have encountered an issue while running my op-geth node. Here’s what I have done so far:

Initialized the op-geth node:
I used the following command to initialize the node with the genesis block:
./build/bin/geth init --datadir=datadir genesis.json

This command executed successfully.

Started the Sequencer node:
I used the following command to start the Sequencer node with archive mode enabled:
./build/bin/geth \
  --datadir ./datadir \
  --http \
  --http.corsdomain="*" \
  --http.vhosts="*" \
  --http.addr=0.0.0.0 \
  --http.api=web3,debug,eth,txpool,net,engine \
  --ws \
  --ws.addr=0.0.0.0 \
  --ws.port=8546 \
  --ws.origins="*" \
  --ws.api=debug,eth,txpool,net,engine \
  --syncmode=full \
  --gcmode=archive \
  --nodiscover \
  --maxpeers=0 \
  --networkid=42069 \
  --authrpc.vhosts="*" \
  --authrpc.addr=0.0.0.0 \
  --authrpc.port=8551 \
  --authrpc.jwtsecret=./jwt.txt \
  --rollup.disabletxpoolgossip=true

However, I am getting the following error:
INFO [09-11|14:23:55.024] Maximum peer count                       ETH=0 total=0
INFO [09-11|14:23:55.025] Smartcard socket not found, disabling    err="stat /run/pcscd/pcscd.comm: no such file or directory"
INFO [09-11|14:23:55.038] Enabling recording of key preimages since archive mode is used
WARN [09-11|14:23:55.039] Disabled transaction unindexing for archive node
WARN [09-11|14:23:55.039] Forcing hash state-scheme for archive mode   
INFO [09-11|14:23:55.039] Set global gas cap                       cap=50,000,000
INFO [09-11|14:23:55.040] Initializing the KZG library             backend=gokzg
INFO [09-11|14:23:55.126] Allocated trie memory caches             clean=307.00MiB dirty=0.00B
INFO [09-11|14:23:55.138] Using pebble as the backing database
INFO [09-11|14:23:55.138] Allocated cache and file handles         database=/mnt/c/Users/HP/Desktop/Lisk/Lisk/op-geth/datadir/geth/chaindata cache=512.00MiB handles=524,288
INFO [09-11|14:23:55.280] Opened ancient database                  database=/mnt/c/Users/HP/Desktop/Lisk/Lisk/op-geth/datadir/geth/chaindata/ancient/chain readonly=false
Fatal: Failed to register the Ethereum service: incompatible state scheme, stored: path, provided: hash



Details:

I’ve ensured that I initialized the op-geth node with the correct genesis block.
I’m running the node with --gcmode=archive because it needs to act as the Sequencer.
I followed the setup instructions from the Optimism documentation, but this error persists.

Questions:

What could be causing the "incompatible state scheme" error?
Are there specific steps or configurations I might be missing?
How can I resolve this issue to successfully start my op-geth node?

Any guidance or troubleshooting tips would be greatly appreciated!

The issue was resolved by adding the --state.scheme=hash flag when initializing the genesis block. Here's the updated command that worked for me:
build/bin/geth init --state.scheme=hash --datadir=datadir genesis.json

After running the above, I was able to start op-geth using:
./build/bin/geth \
  --datadir ./datadir \
  --http \
  --http.corsdomain="*" \
  --http.vhosts="*" \
  --http.addr=0.0.0.0 \
  --http.api=web3,debug,eth,txpool,net,engine \
  --ws \
  --ws.addr=0.0.0.0 \
  --ws.port=8546 \
  --ws.origins="*" \
  --ws.api=debug,eth,txpool,net,engine \
  --syncmode=full \
  --gcmode=archive \
  --nodiscover \
  --maxpeers=0 \
  --networkid=42069 \
  --authrpc.vhosts="*" \
  --authrpc.addr=0.0.0.0 \
  --authrpc.port=8551 \
  --authrpc.jwtsecret=./jwt.txt \
  --rollup.disabletxpoolgossip=true

This solved the 'incompatible state scheme' error I was encountering.
